# How to get dict value from bottle server using python

Tags: python, http, bottle

I wrote this server code:

```
from bottle import run, route, get, post, request, template
import json
import socket
import os
import time


@route('/')
@route('/RegisterMessage/<message_type>', method='GET')
def reg_msg_type(message_type):
    print "Suscribe to", message_type, 'messages'
    if message_type == 'time':
        time = dict()
        time['utc_time'] = 123456
        time['time_zone'] = -120
        return time

#configuring host, port.
run(host='192.168.0.119', port=8088, debug=True)
```

When I go to http://192.168.0.119:8088/RegisterMessage/time in my browser, I get this response:

```
{"time_zone": -120, "utc_time":123456}
```

Now I want to write a client in python which will retrieve those values from my server. I am unable to find anything related to this in the documentation for bottle.

Comment: Reworded to use more helpful language

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of server you're using: it might be `bottle`, `Nginx` or anything. As long as they serve data according to a certain protocol, anyone who can 'speak' this protocol can communicate with the server.

Comment: Search for `python urllib`, don't use `bottle` for your client.